# Rails 5 add column to table and then update view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

I asked Rails to create a simple scaffold:

```
> rails g scaffold Book title:string
```

Then I wanted to add the author:

```
> rails g migration AddAuthorToBooks author:string
```

Next I did a rails db:migrate and restarted my sever. So far, so good.

Finally I modified my form view and my index view by adding the author field (book.author).

I feel like I've done everything right when I enter an author into a new form or a edit an existing record and hit 'submit' I still can't see the author in the resulting HTML view. And, when I check the record in the Rails console it shows a value of nil.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Or what I can check?

Comment: what is sent in `POST` request in the log?

Comment: Unpermitted parameter: author
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "books" ("title", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["title", "Time Flys"], ["created_at", 2017-03-23 02:38:21 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-03-23 02:38:21 UTC]]
   (1.3ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/books/2
Completed 302 Found in 6ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the author column which you've added to the table now to the `book_params` method, something like this:

```
def book_params
  params.require(:book).permit(:title, :author)
end
```

Comment: You're welcome, thanks for the edit suggestion, I haven't noticed it, have fun!